# How to make lapply go through a list using ifelse function in R?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, conditional-statements, lapply

I have two different lists and I want a different plot to output based on which list they are on. Here are the two functions I am using to plot.

```
daily_active_users <- function(data, site_name) {
ggplot(data, aes(x = opened_dates, y = num_active_users, fill = "Blue")) + geom_col() + theme(legend.position = "none") +
labs(title = paste0(site_name, ": Daily # Active Users"), y = "# Active Users")}
```

This is the plot I want to output if the user is in the following dataframe

```
df_table <- data.frame(site_name = c("User1", "User2", "User3"), opened_dates = c("2021-07-01", "2021-08-02", "2021-09-03"), num_active_users = c(5, 18, 11))
```

And if the user is not in this df, I want to use this function to plot

```
default_plot <- function(data, site_name) {
 p <- ggplot(data, aes(NULL, NULL)) +
 geom_blank() +
 theme_void() 

 ggdraw(p) + 
 draw_label("No Data Available", colour = "#80404080", size = 50) }
```

This plot will be based of this dataframe

```
all_sitesList <- data.frame(site_name = c("User1", "User2", "User3", "User4", "User5"))
```

Now I am trying to use ifelse function to plot the first plot (daily_active_users) if the user is in the df_table dataframe but if the user is not in the df_table dataframe, then plot the second default_plot object.

However, when I do this, lapply does not seem to be going through the list. It only outputs stuff for user1. Here is what I am using

```
plts <- function(site_name) {
ifelse(site_name %in% df_table$site_name,  lapply(df_table%>% 
distinct(site_name)%>%pull(site_name), function(x) daily_active_users(df_table, x)) %>% 
setNames(df_table$site_name), lapply(all_sitesList %>% distinct(site_name) %>% pull(site_name), 
function(x) default_plot(df_table, x)) %>%
setNames(all_sitesList$site_name))}
```

Then when I call for User2 for example, using plts("User2"), I get back a plot that has data for User1 as seen by the label at the top of the plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ifelse` function will return a value with the same length as the condition you are checking, so if `length(site_name %in% df_table$site_name)` is 1, you will only get one value back. For example

```
ifelse(5>0, 1:5, 10:20)
# [1] 1
```

only one value is returned and

```
ifelse(c(-5,5)>0, 1:5, 10:20)
# [1] 10  2
```

returns just two values.

You should just use a regular `if() {} else {}` statement in this case.

```
plts <- function(site_name) {
  if(site_name %in% df_table$site_name) {
    lapply(df_table %>%
             distinct(site_name) %>%
             pull(site_name), function(x)
               daily_active_users(df_table, x)) %>%
      setNames(df_table$site_name)    
  } else {
    lapply(all_sitesList %>% distinct(site_name) %>% pull(site_name),
           function(x)
             default_plot(df_table, x)) %>%
      setNames(all_sitesList$site_name)    
  }
}
```

To allow you to pass in more than one site_name, you can do

```
plts <- function(site_name) {
  sites <- unique(site_name)
  lapply(sites, function(site) {
    if(site %in% df_table$site_name) {
      daily_active_users(df_table, site)
    } else {
      default_plot(all_sitesList, x)
    }
  }) %>% setNames(sites)
}
```

Comment: So this does work. But I want the capability to call each plot using the above mechanism. plts("User1"), plts("User2). This just outputs all the plots at once

Comment: I guess it wasn't clear to me what you wanted. I added an additional option that would allow you to pass all the sites at once: `plts(all_sitesList$site_name)`

Comment: Error: Can't add `ggdraw(p)` to a ggplot object. I am getting the following error when I type plts("User4") so it works for whatever is in the df_table but not for users in all_sitesList

Comment: I have no idea where the `ggdraw` function is from. That's not from `ggplot2`. Perhaps you are using some other package that you didn't mentioning the question? I just left that in there because you had it. Are you sure your `default_plot()` function works outside the `plts()` function?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just realized that in the default_plot() function, I forgot to take out the + sign after theme_void().